# How do you override a TableAdapter method on a Table in a DataSet?

Tags: c#, dataset, methods, overriding, tableadapter

I currently have a single DataSet declared which contains 3 tables. For sake of this example we will call them User, Question and Answer.

On each of these I have a TableAdapter with the various methods required, ie. GetData(), Update(), Delete() etc.

On the Answer Table I would like to override the Update Method from the TableAdapter to add some Parameters which are not part of the table, but I need to pass due to the ObjectDataSource requirement.

How do I go about overriding the Update() method on the Answer TableAdapter?

In trying to keep the project simple, I don't want to create a separate DAL layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any designer-generated `TableAdapter` class its appropiate members marked as virtual - this includes the `Update` and `Fill` method among others. Hemce, the solution is simply to inherit from the designer-generated `TableAdapter` class and override the `Update` method, adding your custom code there.

You also have the option of overloading the `Update` method, if you want to change the method signature (parameter count/types). You could do that either on a derived class, or more conveniently in my view, using an extension method:

```
public static void Update(this MyTableAdapter tableAdapter, ... other params ...)
{
    // do stuff here
    tableAdapter.Update(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly I still haven't go the hang of extension methods.

Comment: No problem. And yeah, extension methods do require a slightly mentality change, though you'll love them once you get used to them. :)